# css pseudo class mixin using a variable

Tags: css, mixins, pseudo-element

I want to make the following code work:

```
@mixin wrapper-bg($make-id) {

}
.wrapper-bg:before {
  ...
  background-image: url('/images/makes/{$make-id}.png');
  ...
}
```

Whats my best plan here?

EDIT:
Actually I may be doing this wrong anyway. What I want is a style for each make where the only thing that changes is the image. This css is compiled by gulp so can't inject any php variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand, you are using SASS :) If so, you can do it like this:

```
@mixin wrapper-bg($image-name) {
 &::before {
   background-image: url(/images/makes/#{$image-name}.png);
 } 
}
.wrapper-bg {
  @include wrapper-bg(image-name);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, based on your answer I did the following (as I needed to loop it): \@mixin wrapper-bg($image-id) { &::before { background-image: url(/images/makes/#{$image-id}.png); } } @for $i from 1 through 50 { .wrapper-bg[data-make-id="#{$i}"] { \@include wrapper-bg($i); } }. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I'm assuming you're working with Sass here, so I've come up with the following. You can use a mixin, that takes a variable (in this case id), which will return a `:before{}` tag on the element you apply it to:

```
@mixin wrapper-bg ($id) {
    &:before {
        background-image: url("/images/makes/#{$id}.png");
    }
}

.wrapper-bg {
    @include wrapper-bg("test");
}
```

This will result in:

```
.wrapper-bg:before {
  background-image: url("/images/makes/test.png");
}
```

You can play with the code here: http://codepen.io/offinga/pen/aJbeJM